# App Store Connect Encryption Questions- AES Encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I use AES encryption on my app (it's a game), I encrypt the user data (JSON file) (levels / scores / etc...)
This is how I answered the App Store Connect questions, not sure if it's correct:

*-Does your app use encryption? Select Yes even if your app only uses the standard encryption within Apple’s operating system.*
**YES**

-*Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5
You can select Yes for this question if the encryption of your app is:
(a) Specially designed for medical end-use
(b) Limited to intellectual property and copyright protection
(c) Limited to authentication, digital signature, or the decryption of data or files
(d) Specially designed and limited for banking use or “money transactions”; or
(e) Limited to “fixed” data compression or coding techniques* **NO**

-Does your app implement any encryption algorithms that are proprietary or not accepted as standards by international standard bodies (IEEE, IETF, ITU, etc.)? **NO**

-Does your app implement any standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple’s operating system? **YES**

Is your app going to be available on the App Store in France? **YES**

**Now it's sending me to Encryption page - Add Export Compliance Documentation for** **ITC.apps.universal.platformName.ios**

Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available within Apple’s operating system.) **YES**

Does your app meet any of the following:
(a) Qualifies for one or more exemptions provided under Category 5 Part 2
(b) Use of encryption is limited to encryption within Apple’s operating system
(c) Only makes calls over HTTPS
(d) App is made available only in the U.S. and/or Canada  **NO**

Does your app implement any encryption algorithms that are proprietary or not accepted as standards by international standard bodies (IEEE, IETF, ITU, etc.)? **NO**

Does your app implement any standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple’s operating system? **YES** (**it asks me to submit a copy of your French encryption declaration approval form- not sure what it is so I changed it to NO meanwhile**

Clicked OK and then nothing happens. I'm not sure how to continue from here, In order to submit my app to test flight I need to provide export compliance information, which asks my the questions above, and then sends me to Add Export Compliance Documentation, but nothing was added ...

Comment: "Does your app implement any standard encryption algorithms" should probably be NO if you don't just use the apple OS provided encryption